# ethereum private transaction with flashbots

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, erc20

I have a compromised wallet, where there are bots transferring deposit instantly, so i cant pay fees when trying to move tokens.

I saw a wallet use private transaction with flash-bots for token approvals and other smart contract related functions.

How can i interact with ERC20 tokens and pay fees privately to avoid deposit from being transferred by bots.

so far i have tried using 1inch flash-bots but without ether available i cant access the flash bot option.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: In general I think you want to walk away from a compromised wallet and never look back. It's probably theoretically possible to beat the other bot with flash bots and high max fee / max priority fee though.

Comment: yeah, but how do i implement the flashbots

Comment: Just use the flashbots rpc url instead of whatever you're using

Comment: but how do i make deposit without getting front runned, how will a flashbot rpc help in such case

Comment: This is just theoretical. You should probably abandon that wallet.

Answer (score 0):

To recover the assets from your compromised wallet you need to take three processes (Claim-Unstakes-Transfer) in one single transaction. That's can be done with  Flashbots scripts but you need good javascript and EVM knowledge.